# Rectangle is not union of finite open balls

Tags: general-topology

In book *Introduction to topology* written by Gamelin, page 4,
the author said

> the set $\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2:0<x_1<1,0<x_2<1\}$ is open but is
>   not a finite union of open balls.

Intuitively, it is not difficult to understand this proposition, but how to formally prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an open ball $D(p,r)$ is contained in that rectangle, then the distance from $(0,0)$ to $D(p,r)$ is a number $\varepsilon_{p,r}>0$. So, if you have finitely many open balls $D(p_1,r_1),D(p_n,r_n),\ldots,D(p_n,r_n)$ and if$$\varepsilon=\min\{\varepsilon_{p_1,r_1},\varepsilon_{p_2,r_2}\ldots,\varepsilon_{p_n,r_n}\}$$then the ball $D\bigl((0,0),\varepsilon\bigr)$ contains points of the rectangle which belong to no $D(p_k,r_k)$.